Finding the residue of complex function having pole of order 3
Let C be a positively oriented circle on the complex plane with centre at the origin and radius equal to 3. Then
$\int_c$$\frac{dz}{z^2(e^z - e^{-z})}$ is

$\frac{i\pi}{12}$
$\frac{-i\pi}{12}$
$\frac{i\pi}{6}$
$\frac{-i\pi}{6}$

I know that the above integrand have a pole of order 3 at z=0. I have tried to expand this in laurent series to obtain the residue. Donot know how to do that. I have even tried formula for obtaining residue of pole of order n, but it is only getting complicated. Little help would be appreciated

See Mittag-Leffler expansion for $\operatorname{csch}(z)$

The most elementary trick you can use without having to resort to theorems is to leverage geometric series. Rewriting the integrand, we have
$$\frac{1}{2z^2\left(z+\frac{z^3}{6}+\cdots\right)} = \frac{1}{2z^3\left(1+\frac{z^2}{6}+\cdots\right)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2z^3}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{6}-\cdots\right)=\frac{1}{2z^3}-\frac{1}{12z}-\cdots$$
I'm sure you can take the rest from here.

How did you come from second step to third.

@Alp1091 They wrote, "geometric series".

I understood, thank you
